# 302 Moved Temporarily error

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

In my Customer account menu one of the links gets me redirected to the main customer account page. When I check with Firebug, I see that the status code of the request is `302 Moved Temporarily` and then immediate request to the other page.

This happens when I activate the Itabs_Subcustomer module. Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module, please contact them directly for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically in magento, 302 redirects happen when it encounters a function with something like:

```
$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
```

is encountered. Its just a redirection from a magento controller to somepage else instead of rendering itself.
If the problem as you told is because of that extension, try to go to their controller file and look for code something like above in the controller class to which that link responds. I'm pretty much sure, you'll find something to tweak around.